# Function is ignoring string from array when saving to database

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite

I'm trying to solve this problem over days and I'm completely stuck...

I have a array as follows, I need to process it to ignore zero values and group then into another array to save in db individually, this is an example of the array:

```
array (size=29)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'codigo' => string 'cod' (length=3)
      'values' => 
        array (size=45)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          3 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          4 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          5 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          6 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          7 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          8 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          9 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          10 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          11 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          12 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          13 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          14 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          15 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          16 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          17 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          18 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          19 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          20 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          21 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          22 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          23 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          24 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          25 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          26 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          27 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          28 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          29 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          30 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          31 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          32 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          33 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          34 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          35 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          36 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          37 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          38 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          39 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          40 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          41 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          42 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          43 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          44 => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
```

The values are:

```
array (size=2)
  'codigo' => string 'cod' (length=3)
  'values' => 
    array (size=45)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string '0301' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string '3545' (length=4)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => int 3552
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => int 3553
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string '3547' (length=4)
      5 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => int 3554
      6 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string '0303' (length=4)
      7 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string '3549' (length=4)
      8 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => int 3555
      9 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M025' (length=4)
      10 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M030' (length=4)
      11 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M035' (length=4)
      12 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M040' (length=4)
      13 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M045' (length=4)
      14 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M050' (length=4)
      15 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V055' (length=4)
      16 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V060' (length=4)
      17 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V065' (length=4)
      18 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V070' (length=4)
      19 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V075' (length=4)
      20 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V080' (length=4)
      21 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V085' (length=4)
      22 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V090' (length=4)
      23 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V095' (length=4)
      24 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V100' (length=4)
      25 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V110' (length=4)
      26 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V120' (length=4)
      27 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M025R' (length=5)
      28 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M030R' (length=5)
      29 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M035R' (length=5)
      30 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M040R' (length=5)
      31 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M045R' (length=5)
      32 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'M050R' (length=5)
      33 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V055R' (length=5)
      34 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V060R' (length=5)
      35 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V065R' (length=5)
      36 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V070R' (length=5)
      37 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V075R' (length=5)
      38 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V080R' (length=5)
      39 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V085R' (length=5)
      40 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V090R' (length=5)
      41 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V095R' (length=5)
      42 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V100R' (length=5)
      43 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V110R' (length=5)
      44 => 
        array (size=1)
          'valor' => string 'V120R' (length=5)
```

Other example:

```
array (size=45)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 217.28116928571
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 278.33538214286
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 285.51823071429
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 303.47535214286
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 303.47535214286
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 337.59388285714
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 339.389595
  7 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 377.09955
  8 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => float 402.23969957121
  9 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  10 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  11 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  12 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  13 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  14 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  15 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  16 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  17 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  18 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  19 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  20 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  21 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  22 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  23 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  24 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  25 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  26 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  27 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  28 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  29 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  30 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  31 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  32 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  33 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  34 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  35 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  36 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  37 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  38 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  39 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  40 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  41 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  42 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  43 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
  44 => 
    array (size=1)
      'valor' => int 0
```

I need to ignore this 0 values and add it to another array to save in the database.

This is my code:

```
function getMaxValues(array $array): int
{
    $max = 0;
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        if (count($data['values']) > $max) {
            $max = count($data['values']);
        }
    }
    return $max;
}

function mergeColumns(array $array): array
{
    var_dump($array[0]);
    $titulos = array('tipo1', 'tipo2', 'participantes', 'embutido', 'credito');
    $max = getMaxValues($array);
    $result = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $subResult = [];
        foreach ($array as $data) {
            if (isset($data['values'][$i]) && !in_array($data['codigo'], $titulos)){
                if($data['values'][$i]['valor'] !=0){
                    $subResult[$data['codigo']] = strval($data['values'][$i]);
                }
            }
        }
        $result[] = $subResult;
    }
    return $result;
}

function saveParcelas($data)
{
    $array = mergeColumns($data);
    var_dump($array[9]);
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
        $cod = $array[$x]['cod']['valor'];
        foreach ($array[$x] as $key => $dado) {
            if ($key != 'cod') {            
                $query = "insert into prazoparcela 
                                (codbem, prazo, parcela, admtax) 
                            values ('" .  strval($cod) . "',
                                    " . substr($key, 1) . ",
                                    " . $dado['valor'] . ",0)";
                $db = new SQLite3('../assets/dados.db');
                $db->exec($query);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I have "cod" that are just numbers and some that are strings, this string for some reason that I can't figure out is not saving into database

Can someone lend a helping hand, please?

This is the json that I got from an Excel sheet using a library in js:

```
[{"codigo":"cod","values":[{"valor":"0301"},{"valor":"3545"},{"valor":3552},{"valor":3553},{"valor":"3547"},{"valor":3554},{"valor":"0303"},{"valor":"3549"},{"valor":3555},{"valor":"M025"},{"valor":"M030"},{"valor":"M035"},{"valor":"M040"},{"valor":"M045"},{"valor":"M050"},{"valor":"V055"},{"valor":"V060"},{"valor":"V065"},{"valor":"V070"},{"valor":"V075"},{"valor":"V080"},{"valor":"V085"},{"valor":"V090"},{"valor":"V095"},{"valor":"V100"},{"valor":"V110"},{"valor":"V120"},{"valor":"M025R"},{"valor":"M030R"},{"valor":"M035R"},{"valor":"M040R"},{"valor":"M045R"},{"valor":"M050R"},{"valor":"V055R"},{"valor":"V060R"},{"valor":"V065R"},{"valor":"V070R"},{"valor":"V075R"},{"valor":"V080R"},{"valor":"V085R"},{"valor":"V090R"},{"valor":"V095R"},{"valor":"V100R"},{"valor":"V110R"},{"valor":"V120R"}]},{"codigo":"tipo1","values":[{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Integral"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"},{"valor":"Reduzido"}]},{"codigo":"tipo2","values":[{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fabricante"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"},{"valor":"Fixa"}]},{"codigo":"participantes","values":[{"valor":216},{"valor":216},{"valor":216},{"valor":216},{"valor":216},{"valor":216},{"valor":216},{"valor":216},{"valor":216},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":288},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240},{"valor":240}]},{"codigo":"embutido","values":[{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.1},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15},{"valor":0.15}]},{"codigo":"credito","values":[{"valor":12100},{"valor":15500},{"valor":15900},{"valor":16900},{"valor":16900},{"valor":18800},{"valor":18900},{"valor":21000},{"valor":22400.01},{"valor":25000},{"valor":30000},{"valor":35000},{"valor":40000},{"valor":45000},{"valor":50000},{"valor":55000},{"valor":60000},{"valor":65000},{"valor":70000},{"valor":75000},{"valor":80000},{"valor":85000},{"valor":90000},{"valor":95000},{"valor":100000},{"valor":110000},{"valor":120000},{"valor":25000},{"valor":30000},{"valor":35000},{"valor":40000},{"valor":45000},{"valor":50000},{"valor":55000},{"valor":60000},{"valor":65000},{"valor":70000},{"valor":75000},{"valor":80000},{"valor":85000},{"valor":90000},{"valor":95000},{"valor":100000},{"valor":110000},{"valor":120000}]},{"codigo":"m80","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":947.793},{"valor":1026.77575},{"valor":1105.7585},{"valor":1184.74125},{"valor":1263.724},{"valor":1342.70675},{"valor":1421.6895},{"valor":1500.67225},{"valor":1579.655},{"valor":1737.6205},{"valor":1895.586},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":797.793},{"valor":864.27575},{"valor":930.7585},{"valor":997.24125},{"valor":1063.724},{"valor":1130.20675},{"valor":1196.6895},{"valor":1263.17225},{"valor":1329.655},{"valor":1462.6205},{"valor":1595.586}]},{"codigo":"m77","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m75","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m72","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":1048.633},{"valor":1136.01908333333},{"valor":1223.40516666667},{"valor":1310.79125},{"valor":1398.17733333333},{"valor":1485.56341666667},{"valor":1572.9495},{"valor":1660.33558333333},{"valor":1747.72166666667},{"valor":1922.49383333333},{"valor":2097.266},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":881.953},{"valor":955.449083333333},{"valor":1028.94516666667},{"valor":1102.44125},{"valor":1175.93733333333},{"valor":1249.43341666667},{"valor":1322.9295},{"valor":1396.42558333333},{"valor":1469.92166666667},{"valor":1616.91383333333},{"valor":1763.906}]},{"codigo":"m70","values":[{"valor":217.281169285714},{"valor":278.335382142857},{"valor":285.518230714286},{"valor":303.475352142857},{"valor":303.475352142857},{"valor":337.593882857143},{"valor":339.389595},{"valor":377.09955},{"valor":402.239699571214},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m68","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m65","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":482.177211538462},{"valor":578.612653846154},{"valor":675.048096153846},{"valor":771.483538461538},{"valor":867.918980769231},{"valor":964.354423076923},{"valor":0},{"valor":1157.22530769231},{"valor":1253.66075},{"valor":1350.09619230769},{"valor":1446.53163461538},{"valor":1542.96707692308},{"valor":1639.40251923077},{"valor":1735.83796153846},{"valor":1832.27340384615},{"valor":1928.70884615385},{"valor":2121.57973076923},{"valor":2314.45061538461},{"valor":405.252211538462},{"valor":486.302653846154},{"valor":567.353096153846},{"valor":648.403538461538},{"valor":729.453980769231},{"valor":810.504423076923},{"valor":0},{"valor":972.605307692308},{"valor":1053.65575},{"valor":1134.70619230769},{"valor":1215.75663461538},{"valor":1296.80707692308},{"valor":1377.85751923077},{"valor":1458.90796153846},{"valor":1539.95840384615},{"valor":1621.00884615385},{"valor":1783.10973076923},{"valor":1945.21061538462}]},{"codigo":"m63","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m60","values":[{"valor":252.134355},{"valor":322.982025},{"valor":331.317045},{"valor":352.154595},{"valor":352.154595},{"valor":391.74594},{"valor":393.829695},{"valor":437.58855},{"valor":466.7613283755},{"valor":520.93875},{"valor":625.1265},{"valor":729.31425},{"valor":833.502},{"valor":937.68975},{"valor":1041.8775},{"valor":0},{"valor":1250.253},{"valor":1354.44075},{"valor":1458.6285},{"valor":1562.81625},{"valor":1667.004},{"valor":1771.19175},{"valor":1875.3795},{"valor":1979.56725},{"valor":2083.755},{"valor":2292.1305},{"valor":2500.506},{"valor":437.61375},{"valor":525.1365},{"valor":612.65925},{"valor":700.182},{"valor":787.70475},{"valor":875.2275},{"valor":0},{"valor":1050.273},{"valor":1137.79575},{"valor":1225.3185},{"valor":1312.84125},{"valor":1400.364},{"valor":1487.88675},{"valor":1575.4095},{"valor":1662.93225},{"valor":1750.455},{"valor":1925.5005},{"valor":2100.546}]},{"codigo":"m57","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m55","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m53","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m50","values":[{"valor":300.945755},{"valor":385.509025},{"valor":395.457645},{"valor":420.329195},{"valor":420.329195},{"valor":467.58514},{"valor":470.072295},{"valor":522.30255},{"valor":557.1229687155},{"valor":621.78875},{"valor":746.1465},{"valor":870.50425},{"valor":994.862},{"valor":1119.21975},{"valor":1243.5775},{"valor":0},{"valor":1492.293},{"valor":1616.65075},{"valor":1741.0085},{"valor":1865.36625},{"valor":1989.724},{"valor":2114.08175},{"valor":2238.4395},{"valor":2362.79725},{"valor":2487.155},{"valor":2735.8705},{"valor":2984.586},{"valor":521.78875},{"valor":626.1465},{"valor":730.50425},{"valor":834.862},{"valor":939.21975},{"valor":1043.5775},{"valor":0},{"valor":1252.293},{"valor":1356.65075},{"valor":1461.0085},{"valor":1565.36625},{"valor":1669.724},{"valor":1774.08175},{"valor":1878.4395},{"valor":1982.79725},{"valor":2087.155},{"valor":2295.8705},{"valor":2504.586}]},{"codigo":"m47","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m45","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m43","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},{"codigo":"m40","values":[{"valor":374.150755},{"valor":479.284025},{"valor":491.652645},{"valor":522.574195},{"valor":522.574195},{"valor":581.32514},{"valor":584.417295},{"valor":649.35255},{"valor":692.6430292155},{"valor":773.03875},{"valor":927.6465},{"valor":1082.25425},{"valor":1236.862},{"valor":1391.46975},{"valor":1546.0775},{"valor":0},{"valor":1855.293},{"valor":2009.90075},{"valor":2164.5085},{"valor":2319.11625},{"valor":2473.724},{"valor":2628.33175},{"valor":2782.9395},{"valor":2937.54725},{"valor":3092.155},{"valor":3401.3705},{"valor":3710.586},{"valor":648.03875},{"valor":777.6465},{"valor":907.25425},{"valor":1036.862},{"valor":1166.46975},{"valor":1296.0775},{"valor":0},{"valor":1555.293},{"valor":1684.90075},{"valor":1814.5085},{"valor":1944.11625},{"valor":2073.724},{"valor":2203.33175},{"valor":2332.9395},{"valor":2462.54725},{"valor":2592.155},{"valor":2851.3705},{"valor":3110.586}]},{"codigo":"m38","values":[{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0},{"valor":0}]},]}]
```

and this is the sheet:

[image: excel sheet]

```
CREATE TABLE "prazoparcela" 
(
    "codbem" TEXT NOT NULL, 
    "prazo" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "parcela" REAL NOT NULL, 
    "admtax" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY("codbem") REFERENCES "credito" 
);
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: How do you create the original array?

Comment: the original array was imported over a sheet by javascript, I put this data in a input and sent to php over POST

I'm not worried about sql inject by now, as soon I can solve this problem I will deal with it

Comment: _over a sheet_?

Comment: yes, a excel sheet, I used a js plugin to convert the data from the sheet to a json, added also a print from the sheet

Comment: I added the json that I got by the sheet

Comment: Are you getting any error messages

Comment: no, any error, the values are being saved to db, but the cod field when it is a string, don´t

Comment: Can you show the schema for this table please

Comment: _no, any error_ Well thats odd, I get errors! If you add these lines to the top of the script `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Do you get errors now

Comment: I added the code error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); but there's no effect

Comment: the schema is 
CREATE TABLE "prazoparcela" (
 "codbem" TEXT NOT NULL,
 "prazo" INTEGER NOT NULL,
 "parcela" REAL NOT NULL,
 "admtax" INTEGER NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY("codbem") REFERENCES "credito"
);

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some errors you claim were not there, you were addressing some of the arrays incorrectly (check each line carefully)

I also amended the code to remove the [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) issues.

```
function getMaxValues(array $array): int
{
    $max = 0;
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        if (count($data['values']) > $max) {
            $max = count($data['values']);
        }
    }
    return $max;
}

function mergeColumns(array $array): array
{
    #var_dump($array[0]);
    $titulos = array('tipo1', 'tipo2', 'participantes', 'embutido', 'credito');
    $max = getMaxValues($array);
    $result = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $subResult = [];
        foreach ($array as $data) {
            if (isset($data['values'][$i]) && !in_array($data['codigo'], $titulos)){
                if($data['values'][$i]['valor'] !=0){
                    $subResult[$data['codigo']] = strval($data['values'][$i]['valor']);
                }
            }
        }
        $result[] = $subResult;
    }
    return $result;
}

function saveParcelas($data)
{
    // this can be done ones and then reused
    $query = "insert into prazoparcela (codbem, prazo, parcela, admtax) 
                values (:codbem, :prazo, :parcela, 0)";
    
    $db = new SQLite3('../assets/dados.db');

    // prepare the query, SQL Injection protection + ease of use
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    // tell the prepared query which PHP variables will hold the parameter values
    // again do this only one
    $stmt->bindParam(':codbem', $cod, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':prazo', $key, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $stmt->bindParam(':parcela', $dado, SQLITE3_FLOAT);
    
    $array = mergeColumns($data);
    #var_dump($array[9]);
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
        $cod = $array[$x]['cod'];
        foreach ($array[$x] as $key => $dado) {
            if ($key != 'cod') {            
                // execute the prepared query, having set the PHP variables 
                // with the values for this particular execution of the query
                // $code, $fixed_key and $dado
                $key = substr($key,1);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```